# vuejs + Firebase remove/update grandchildren

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I just started to create an app with Vuejs + firebase, and I am having problems to update or remove grandchildren items.

To create a grandchild I have successfully used the following:

```
spotsRefs.child(spot['.key']).child('pictures').push(picture)
```

but for removing a grandchild, it doesn't work I am trying something like this:

```
spotsRefs.child(spot['.key']).child('pictures').child(picture).remove()
```

For updating the grandchild I am not really sure how to get the autogenerated -**LZJYrFFx9RMdiqMv5dv** id

this is how it looks in the console:

[image]

I have 2 different functions, for create and delete:

```
this.$root.$on('create', (spot, picture) => {
      spotsRefs.child(spot['.key']).child('pictures').push(picture);
});



this.$root.$on('delete', (spot, picture) => {
       spotsRefs.child(spot['.key']).child('pictures').child(picture).remove()
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass using child key instead of `.child(picture)`

Get the reference to added child:

```
const addedChildRef = spotsRefs.child(spot['.key']).child('pictures').push(picture)
```

and then remove

```
spotsRefs.child(spot['.key']).child('pictures').child(addedChildRef.key).remove()
```

or

```
addedChildRef.remove()
```

Comment: owww that is a great idea!! and it works well! thank you so much
... only thing is that, do I need to store the addedChildRef somewhere? not sure how to use it when it comes to many children

Comment: I'm not sure how do you organize data and component? Do you bind data directly from firebase?

Comment: I have 2 separated functions for create and edit, please look at the question, I have added the functions. Thaank you!

Comment: I stored the value of the addedChildRef in the object, i couldn't find a better way to do this... so I am marking this as the right answer...